# Erro no Windows 10: Error retrieving parent for item

Tags: android, windows-10

Estou com este problema aqui:

> Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Acho que é por causa do android studio ainda não seja compatível para o windows 10.

Comment: Não sei se você leu a mensagem ou se tentou usar o tradutor para traduzi-la, mas não tem nada a ver com compatibilidade não viu :) #ficadica

Comment: Você baixou o ultimo SDK?

Comment: @PauloRoberto Tem a ver com o que?

Comment: Isso pode ser por a versão indicada em `compileSdkVersion` ser diferente da versão da *appcompat*. Poste o *build.gradle*.

Comment: Só mantive o Windows10 no titulo, porque provavelmente o autor testou em outra versão do windows e funcionou, mas não dá pra ter certeza. Todavia dei enfase ao que interessa, a mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2):

conforme a [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32075678/1518921) e nesta outra [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32239866/1518921) não é um problema com o Windows e sim com o *Android SDK*, isto provavelmente ocorre por que após o update o padrão seja o **api version 23**.

Sua versão SDK compilação deve coincidir com a versão principal biblioteca de suporte.

Desde que você está usando a versão 23 da biblioteca, você precisa compilar na versão 23 do *Android SDK*.

Alternativamente, você pode continuar a compilação na versão 22 do *Android SDK* por mudar para a biblioteca v22.

Aperte <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> e vá até *project structure* e troque por *23.0.0* to *22.0.1*

> Nota: quando instalar o Studio eu coloco alguns prints de tela